# Integrate Factorial

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Straight to question, how do you analytically integrate factorial function like the following:
$\int_0^\infty 1/(n-1)!\, \mathrm dn\
$. This is equivalent to 
$\int_0^\infty 1/Γ(n)\, \mathrm dn\
$ but how do you integrate something like this. Using grapher shows a nice smooth graph that converges quickly.

Comment: Use the reflection formula for the Gamma function and then its integral definition

Comment: I still don't get it, can you please show me. 

Comment: [The Fransén–Robinson constant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fransén–Robinson_constant)

Comment: Never heard of it, thanks for introducing it to me.

Comment: See [equation (3) of the Lambda function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambdaFunction.html) and [Nu function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuFunction.html) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A hint.**

Your integral is:

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\Gamma(x)}$$

By reflection formula for the Gamma function:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}=\frac{1}{\pi} \Gamma(1-x) \sin \pi x$$

$$I=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \Gamma(1-x) \sin \pi x~ dx$$

Now by the integral definition of the Gamma function we get:

$$\Gamma(1-x)= \int_0^\infty  \frac{e^{-t}}{t^x}dt$$

So now the integral becomes:

$$I=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty  \int_0^\infty \sin (\pi x)~ \frac{e^{-t}}{t^x}~dt ~ dx$$

$$I=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty  \int_0^\infty \sin (\pi x)~ e^{- \ln(t) x} e^{-t}~dt ~ dx$$

See @nospoon's comment. No closed form is available, apparently, but maybe this hint might still help.

Comment: I get it now, thanks.